# Mysqli "SELECT * FROM" loop

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I'm making the jump to mysqli/PDO at the moment, and am converting a SELECT loop from the "old" method to mysqli.

The "old" method:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);       

$i=0;

while ($i < $num) {
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"surname");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"pcode");
    $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"transaction_id");
    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"articles");
    $f6=mysql_result($result,$i, "delivery");

    //echo out to table here

    $i++;

}
```

I've got as far as the basic mysqli query, and then simply attempted to replicate the while loop above:

```
if ($pending_stmt=$mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE status = ?')) {
    $pending_stmt->bind_param('s', $status); //$status is set prior to if statement
    $pending_stmt->execute();
    $pending_stmt->store_result();
    $pending_stmt->fetch_all();

    $rows=$pending_stmt->num_rows();

    $i=0;

    while ($i < $rows) {
        $f1=$pending_stmt->fetch($i,'pcode');

        //echo out to table here

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Needless to say, it's not working... and after much searching, I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough as to give me some pointers.

Comment: Could you be more explicit then "it's not working"?

Comment: It's not working... as in it's not returning any results.

Answer (score 1):

No wonder it is not working. You are mixing everything up. You don't need `store_result()`, `fetch_all()` or `num_rows()`. `fetch()` cannot navigate to a particular row and column like `mysql_result()` did.
You have two options how to solve it.

1. Using `get_result()`

   ```
   $pending_stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT columnA, columnB FROM transactions WHERE status = ?');
   $pending_stmt->bind_param('s', $status); //$status is set prior to if statement
   $pending_stmt->execute();
   $result = $pending_stmt->get_result();

   foreach ($result as $row) {
       echo $row['columnA'];
       echo $row['columnB'];
   }
   ```
2. Using `store_result()`, `bind_result()` and `fetch()`

   ```
   $pending_stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT columnA, columnB FROM transactions WHERE status = ?');
   $pending_stmt->bind_param('s', $status); //$status is set prior to if statement
   $pending_stmt->execute();
   $pending_stmt->store_result(); // recommended, but not necessary
   $pending_stmt->bind_result($f1, $f2);

   while ($pending_stmt->fetch()) {
       echo $f1;
       echo $f2;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$pending_stmt->execute(array($status));
$result = $pending_stmt->fetchAll();
```

I didn't understand why you use the count var, try a for each:

```
foreach($result as $item) {
    $f1 = $item['pcode'];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it hasn't worked. I'm looking at bind_result() atm.

Comment: Please, see on apache errors log. This should work, if not try to see if you are setup the $mysqli correctly.